# regex find all utf8 text, started with # and end by space or enter

Tags: regex

I want render Utf8 text and link all tag that started with `#` and ended with `space` or `enter` or any separator such as `\r` `\t` `\n`.

text example:

```
Текстовые теги #общий #тест
Хиджаб в исламе, философии безопасности #женщин
english #teg #test
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "separator"?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I use PHP programming language .

Comment: OK, so where's your code? What have you tried? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Maybe [`/\B#\p{Xwd}+/u`](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/gAO#preg-match-all) .. It depends on what you mean by "*started*" and "*any separator*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you also want to get those with the normal ascii characters

Then this:

```
<?php
$description = 'Текстовые теги #общий #тест
Хиджаб в исламе, философии безопасности #женщин
english #teg #test';

preg_match_all('/(?<=#)\w+(?=\s|$)/u',$description,$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

var_dump($matches);
```

Would get you an array with: 
`"общий","тест","женщин","teg","test"`

The u modifier makes it so that \w also captures the unicode word characters.
The \w is equivalent to `[\p{L}\p{N}_]`: letters, numbers or underscore.

The `(?<=#)` is a positive lookbehind that tells regex that before the \w+ there needs to be a #

The `(?=\s|$)` is a positive lookahead that tells the regex that after the \w+ there needs to be an invisible character (\s is equivalent to `[\p{Z}\h\v]`).
Or the end of the line `$` (to also capture `test` that has no \s behind it).

But you might want to remove that positive lookahead. Unless you NEED it to be followed by a whitespace because for example `#общий!` shouldn't be matched.

If you need it to be more specific, I suggest you look at what you can do with those \p{} [here](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)
And play around with them, for example [here](https://regex101.com/)